# Some numbers are incorrectly changed when i try to find prime numbers in matrix

Tags: c

I try to find prime numbers in a matrix and replace then with 1 and 0 respectively. For some the output is correct but for some it isn't and it doesn't change the last element. Can't figure out what's causing this. Looked up formulas for finding prime numbers they use the same loop as i do.

```
int main() {
    int m, n;
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    int a[m][n];

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for(int k = 2; k < a[i][j]; k++) {
                if(a[i][j] % k == 0) {
                    a[i][j] = 0;
                } else if(a[i][j] % k != 0){
                    a[i][j] = 1;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

`15 23 7 10
 6 18 5 31
 31 14 1 2`

Output im getting:

`1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 1
 1 0 1 2`

Output i need to get:

`0 1 1 0
 0 0 1 1
 1 0 0 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of a prime test stop iterating after the number is noted as *not prime*.

```
        int p = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = p > 1;
        for(int k = 2; k < p; k++) {
            if(p % k == 0) {
                a[i][j] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Even better, no need to iterate until `k < p`.  Code can stop sooner with  `k*k <= p` or better as `k <= p/k`.  Consider if `p` was near 1,000,000.  Rather than 1,000,000 loops, code does as most 1,000 loops - much faster.

```
        // for(int k = 2; k < p; k++) {
        for(int k = 2; k <= p/k; k++) {
```

Comment: Good quick catch!

Comment: Thank you it worked. Do you mind telling me why did you use this `a[i][j] = p > 1`? Also i did see some formulas use `p / k`, but it didn't explain why so i didn't wanna use it.

Comment: @Stefan `a[i][j] = p > 1` set values greater than or equal to 2 as potential primes and values less than 2 as not prime.

Comment: @Stefan Does `k*k <= p` make sense?